# Multiple filters on a Path i.e. file

Tags: java, spring, java-stream

I have a question on the following code:

```java
import java.io.*
import java.nio.*
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

public static void FileReader { 
    String filePath = "C:\Downloads\"";
    Stream<Path> walk = Files.walk(Paths.get(filePath));
    List<Resource> result = walk
                           .map(file -> file.toString())
                           .filter(file -> file.endsWith(".json"))
                           .map(file -> new FileSystemResource(file))
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
    walk.close()
}
```

Can you have multiple filters on file, such as one for if the file ends in `.zip`?

Comment: A Predicate can consist of any logic you want, as long as the expression evaluates to a boolean:  `filter(file -> file.endsWith(".json") || file.endsWith(".zip"))`

Comment: Is it really possible to have code straight inside a class and not in some method?

Comment: @JanSchultke good point. Fixed the code for ya ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word - yes.

First, your filter could contain several conditions joined together with some logical operator, e.g.:

```
List<Resource> result = walk
                       .map(file -> file.toString())
                       .filter(file -> file.endsWith(".json") || file.endsWith(".zip")
                       .map(file -> new FileSystemResource(file))
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Second, you could have multiple `filter` calls and you can mix them up anywhere before the terminating call, e.g.:

```
List<Resource> result = walk
                       .map(file -> file.toString())
                       .filter(file -> file.endsWith(".json"))
                       .map(file -> new FileSystemResource(file))
                       .filter(f -> f != null) // Or something more meaningful...
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: That `f != null` filter doesn't make sense to me. You always construct a `new FileSystemResource`, so why would the elements in the stream ever be `null`?

Comment: @JanSchultke It's a redundant condition just to demonstrate you can have multiple `filter` calls.

Comment: @Mureinik Can I call a method within the filter? Such as, if ```.filter(f -> f.endsWith(".zip"))  ```then call unzipFolder method

Comment: @cluis92 If you want to transform the contents of the stream, you should use `map`, not `filter`.